# HtmlUnit - ScriptException: Exception invoking drawImage

Tags: java, android, exception, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit on my android project:

```
implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit-android', version: '2.67.0'
```

I am simply try to get a webpage:

```
private final static String LOGIN_URL = "https://sso.pokemon.com/sso/login?locale=en&service=https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/caslogin";
    private final static WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(LOGIN_URL);
```

However this is the exception I get at runtime:

```
  ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    Exception class=[java.lang.RuntimeException]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking drawImage
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:1001)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:590)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:484)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:349)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:928)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:900)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2620)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2613)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:173)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.lambda$fireEvent$0(DomElement.java:1496)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:590)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:484)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:349)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1496)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.fireEvent(HtmlImage.java:949)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.doOnLoad(HtmlImage.java:319)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage$1.execute(HtmlImage.java:165)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:710)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:592)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:510)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:417)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:555)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:537)
        at com.test.xxx.thread.PTCThread.run(PTCThread.java:58)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking drawImage
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:238)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:405)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1876)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1053)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:89)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:392)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:335)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3916)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:921)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:984)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:590) 
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:484) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:349) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:928) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:900) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2620) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2613) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:173) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.lambda$fireEvent$0(DomElement.java:1496) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:590) 
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:484) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:349) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1496) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.fireEvent(HtmlImage.java:949) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.doOnLoad(HtmlImage.java:319) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage$1.execute(HtmlImage.java:165) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:342) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:710) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:592) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:510) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:417) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:555) 
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:537) 
        at com.test.xxx.thread.PTCThread.run(PTCThread.java:58) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/imageio/ImageIO;
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.readImageIfNeeded(HtmlImage.java:702)
2022-12-05 08:28:08.823 14255-14815/com.test.xxx E/JavaScriptErrorListener:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.getImageReader(HtmlImage.java:619)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.canvas.CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage(CanvasRenderingContext2D.java:410)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:215)
            ... 36 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.imageio.ImageIO" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~uPm2D4x2H8UJPMnJkCz-fQ==/com.test.xxx-7vAaguDgQshpcmtUKuBo6g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~uPm2D4x2H8UJPMnJkCz-fQ==/com.test.xxx-7vAaguDgQshpcmtUKuBo6g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 41 more
    Enclosed exception: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking drawImage
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:238)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:405)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1876)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1053)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:89)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:392)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:335)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3916)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:921)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:984)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:590)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:484)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:349)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:928)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:900)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2620)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2613)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:173)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.lambda$fireEvent$0(DomElement.java:1496)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:590)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:484)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:349)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1496)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.fireEvent(HtmlImage.java:949)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.doOnLoad(HtmlImage.java:319)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage$1.execute(HtmlImage.java:165)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:710)
2022-12-05 08:28:08.823 14255-14815/com.test.xxx E/JavaScriptErrorListener:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:592)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:510)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:417)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:555)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:537)
        at com.test.xxx.thread.PTCThread.run(PTCThread.java:58)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/imageio/ImageIO;
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.readImageIfNeeded(HtmlImage.java:702)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.getImageReader(HtmlImage.java:619)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.canvas.CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage(CanvasRenderingContext2D.java:410)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:215)
            ... 36 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.imageio.ImageIO" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~uPm2D4x2H8UJPMnJkCz-fQ==/com.test.xxx-7vAaguDgQshpcmtUKuBo6g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~uPm2D4x2H8UJPMnJkCz-fQ==/com.test.xxx-7vAaguDgQshpcmtUKuBo6g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 41 more
    == CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
      function () {
          c.drawImage(a, 0, 0), Modernizr.addTest("todataurljpeg", function () {
              return b.toDataURL("image/jpeg").indexOf("data:image/jpeg") === 0;
          }), Modernizr.addTest("todataurlwebp", function () {
              return b.toDataURL("image/webp").indexOf("data:image/webp") === 0;
          });
      }
    ======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

The issue seems to be the fact that it's not able to find the class imageIO in the DexPathList, am I correct? If so, how to fix this?

I am also getting a few warnings regarding the CSS parser but I don't think are relevant:

```
022-12-05 08:27:55.668 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.679 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.701 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.706 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.718 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.721 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.736 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.740 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.763 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.766 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.782 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.786 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.803 14255-14731/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Background concurrent copying GC freed 345290(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 32(2284KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 9852KB/19MB, paused 101us total 147.448ms
2022-12-05 08:27:55.806 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.806 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.819 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.820 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.824 14255-14735/com.test.xxx W/System: A resource failed to call dispose. 
2022-12-05 08:27:55.829 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.831 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.840 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.842 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.852 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.853 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.862 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.864 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.873 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.875 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.901 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.901 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.904 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.905 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.922 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.922 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.923 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.923 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.930 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.931 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.941 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.942 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.949 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.953 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.961 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.963 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.973 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.974 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.983 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.984 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.994 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:55.996 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.003 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.005 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.014 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.015 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.025 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.026 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.037 14255-14815/com.test.xxx W/DefaultCssErrorHandler: CSS error: 'https://assets.pokemon.com/static2/_ui/css/main.css' [1:42772] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
2022-12-05 08:27:56.042 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.046 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.061 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.061 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.068 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.071 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.079 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.081 14255-14730/com.test.xxx I/rt.xxx: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 46318 in int com.gargoylesoftware.css.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
2022-12-05 08:27:56.193 14255-14815/com.test.xxx W/DefaultCssErrorHandler: CSS error: 'https://assets.pokemon.com/static2/_ui/css/main.css' [1:65685] Error in declaration. '*' is not allowed as first char of a property.
```

Comment: Please open an issue on github - https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android

Comment: @RBRi but I am not sure it's an issue of HtmlUnit since the error seems to be with the class imageIO in the DexPathList.

Comment: Yes the imageio stuff is not available on Android - i will try to make the call a noop when using HtmlUnit on Android.

Comment: Okay! Will you let me know when it's fixed?

Comment: maybe :-) - of course i will and there is also a twitter account if you like to be on track (https://twitter.com/htmlunit)

Comment: Thanks! :) From which version did you start using imageIO? Because with 2.15 there was no issue with imageIO. My app, as a matter of fact, was built with 2.15 but stopped working few months ago and thought to update htmlunit :)

Comment: still waiting for the issue....

Comment: ImageIO usage was there also in 2.12 but maybe the web page has changed or we have done some other fixes that forcing the image resolution now.
Please open the issue and let it discuss there.

Comment: Posted the issue on github!

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new android version of HtmlUnit (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android) that should solve most of the issues related to not existing classes in the android jdk (including this imageio problem).

This also requires to update your sources to HtmlUnit3 - see https://www.htmlunit.org/migration.html.

Comment: I am still getting quite a few of issues. Should I open a new question here or directly on GitHub?

Comment: Please on github, at least for me it is easier to track

Comment: Posted a question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061390/htmlunit-exception-invoking-drawimage-due-to-awt-color-missing

and a new issue on GitHub: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android/issues/27

Comment: the (simple) parts of the problems are already fixed, more will come